# How to check if class has method with given name and input parameters but any return type?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am using C++20, so I can use concepts and it is preferable.
I want to check class `Token` has method `<ANY> get_executor();` and pass the result to `if constexpr`, so it would be something like:

```
class Token;

template <typename T>
concept has_method_get_executor = <???>;

if constexpr (has_method_get_executor<Token>())
{
...
}
else
{
...
}
```

How can I write such concept? If it is easier without concepts, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Is there something wrong with just using a `requires` clause? Also, what is `has_method_get_executor`, and is it supposed to be the same as `has_resize_member_func`?

Comment: Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/WccTovdcP)?

Answer (score 0):

There could be some complications with overloading, or private class methods, but the basic use case is fairly straightforward:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
concept has_method_get_executor = requires(T &&t) {
    {t.get_executor() };
};

class Token {

public:
    bool get_executor();
};

class Token2 {};

bool foo()
{
    if constexpr (has_method_get_executor<Token>)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool foo2()
{
    if constexpr (has_method_get_executor<Token2>)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo() << "\n"; // Result: 1
    std::cout << foo2() << "\n"; // Result: 0
    return 0;
}
```